# Pillow - KeyError when trying to write text on an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write some text onto an image in Pillow, but for some reason it seems to constantly error out about a KeyError. I've tested this with multiple pre-written examples, so I'm fairly sure it's not my code. Here's a copy of the script and the error I'm getting:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype("F25_Bank_Printer.ttf", 16)

img = Image.open('background.png')

title_text = "AUUUUUGH"
image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
image_editable.text((15,15), title_text, (237,230,211), font=font)


img.save('test_card.png')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 99, in getcolor
    return self.colors[color]
KeyError: (237, 230, 211)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hbag/git/novelty-scripts/scripts/probebadge.py", line 9, in <module>
    image_editable.text((15,15), title_text, (237,230,211), font=font)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 339, in text
    ink = getink(fill)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 302, in getink
    ink, fill = self._getink(fill)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 112, in _getink
    ink = self.palette.getcolor(ink)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py", line 109, in getcolor
    self.palette[index + 256] = color[1]
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

And, just to be safe, here's the image I'm trying to draw on:
[image: A plain, redish-pink rectangle.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your problem is that the image you are trying to edit is indexed, that means that it doesn't have RGB colors available, but only a limited palette of colors. So `(237,230,211)` is not a RGB tuple, but indexes into the palette of the image.

By converting the image to RGB before trying to draw on it, you should be able to make it work:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype("F25_Bank_Printer.ttf", 16)

img = Image.open('background.png')
img = img.convert('RGB')

title_text = "AUUUUUGH"
image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
image_editable.text((15,15), title_text, (237,230,211), font=font)


img.save('test_card.png')
```